# Images not displaying when using Slimmage and Orchard Output Cache

Tags: orchardcms, imageresizer

We are using Orchard with Image Resizer and Slimmage per the instructions from [this article](http://imageresizing.net/blog/2013/effortless-responsive-images).

Everything was going fine until we turned on the Output Cache module, when we turned it on none of the images are rendering at all. When I inspect the container div in the browser, the container is empty. A hard refresh will render the images, but after that a regular page load/reload will not render any images.

When I view the source, inside the container div the code looks like this:

```
<noscript data-slimmage="true" data-img-src="/Media/Default/images/photo.jpg?slimmage=true&width=375&quality=60" data-img-alt="">
    <noscript data-slimmage="true" data-img-src="/Media/Default/images/photo.jpg?slimmage=true&width=375&quality=60" data-img-alt="">
        <img src="/Media/Default/images/photo.jpg?slimmage=true&width=375&quality=60" alt="">
    </noscript>
</noscript>
```

Looks to me like the cached version of the page already has the `<noscript>` tag around all the img tags with slimmage enabled, and it's getting processed a second time. Then slimmage is searching through the page for the `<noscript>` tag, finding it, and seeing another `<noscript>` instead of an `<img>` tag so it stops processing.

Answer (score 0):

I have a fix, but it's more of a work-around than a solution.

Everywhere in my code that looked like this:

```
<img src="/Media/Default/images/photo.jpg?slimmage=true&width=375&quality=60" alt="">
```

I replaced it with this:

```
<noscript data-slimmage="true" data-img-src="/Media/Default/images/photo.jpg?width=375&quality=60" data-img-alt="">
    <img src="/Media/Default/images/photo.jpg?width=375&quality=60" alt="">
</noscript>
```

By eliminating `slimmage=true` in the query string it's no longer being processed by SlimResponse.